# JSON that contains an array to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, ios7

How do I extract each address from the NSDictionary I instantiated (below), so I can assign to various NSString objects?

I have the following JSON:

```
{
   "Address":[
      {
         "$":{
            "ID":"0"
         },
         "Address2":[
            "10 Smith RD"
         ],
         "City":[
            "Mapleville"
         ],
         "State":[
            "NJ"
         ],
         "Zip5":[
            "90210"
         ],
         "Zip4":[
            "764"
         ]
      },
      {
         "$":{
            "ID":"1"
         },
         "Address2":[
            "32 Hog CT"
         ],
         "City":[
            "New York City"
         ],
         "State":[
            "NY"
         ],
         "Zip5":[
            "90210"
         ],
         "Zip4":[
            "1390"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

cData (below) came from the JSON above.
I did the following to convert to a NSDictionary:

```
NSDictionary* dictionary2 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:cData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
```

once I did a:

```
NSLog(@"%@", dictionary2);
```

output from NSLog:

```
{
    Address =     (
                {
            "$" =             {
                ID = 0;
            };
            Address2 =             (
                "10 Smith RD"
            );
            City =             (
                "Mapleville"
            );
            State =             (
                NJ
            );
            Zip4 =             (
                7642
            );
            Zip5 =             (
                90210
            );
        },
                {
            "$" =             {
                ID = 1;
            };
            Address2 =             (
                "32 Hog CT"
            );
            City =             (
                "New York City"
            );
            State =             (
                NY
            );
            Zip4 =             (
                1390
            );
            Zip5 =             (
                90210
            );
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: You have an `NSDictionary`. You get data from it like always. The fact that is was created from JSON is irrelevant at that point.

Comment: I included that information to be precise. I'm having difficulty getting the values for each address because the key is "$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow the structure.

```
NSDictionary* dictionary2 = [NSJSONSerialization ...
NSArray *addresses = dictionary2[@"Address"];
for (NSDictionary *addressData in addresses) {
    NSString *address2 = addressData[@"Address2"];
    NSString *city = addressData[@"City"];
    // and the rest as needed
}
```

Comment: Thank for your time and effort. That worked. This was my first time using NSDictionary.